# Thymeleaf throwing error on Google Analytics Code

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Im trying to add Google Analytics to my webpage but Thymeleaf is throwing the error `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Referenz zu Entity "l" muss mit dem Begrenzungszeichen ";" enden.` 
Translation: after "l" the entitity must end with ";"

Any Ideas how to solve this Problem?

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5SNB8LZ')
```

The error refers to this line of the Google Analytics Code

```
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
```

Comment: I think issue is in copy pasting google analytics code in html .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
... Your script
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: @pepote Please take a look to the edited answer, I've tried it and I didn't get any error

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is actually with '&' symbol.

If you change  `?'&l='` to `?'&amp;l='` it will work. At least worked for me.